# Library for FLV/F4V conversation in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, flash, video, flv

Is there any library that can covert input video (of some specific video files) to f4v or flv programatically in c# .NET?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This code does the trick pretty well: http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/

ps. you can easily modify it if you need any extra features of ffmpeg. We did, only because we are using it to slice music/videos, but you should be able to use it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/